# I can't find why my program always says too low

Tags: c

So I've been working on a small program, which makes a file, then makes a child process that generates a random number in that file, than have my parent process read the number, and play a simple higher or lower game. Whenever I run this, no matter what number I put in it always says too low. Where is the error?

```
int main()
{
int fd, m;

    if (mkfifo("myfifo", 0666) < 0)
            perror("mkfifo"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
            fd = open("myfifo", O_WRONLY);
            srand(time(NULL));
            int n = rand() % 100 + 1;
            close(fd);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    fd = open("myfifo", O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, &m, sizeof(int));
    int c = -1;
    while ( m != c )
    {
            if ( c == -1)
                    printf("Guess a number 1-100\n");
            else if (c > m)
                    printf("Too high!\n");
            else if (c < m)
                    printf("Too low!\n");

            printf("Enter your guess: ");
            scanf ("%d",&c);
    }
    printf("Winner! Yes, the answer was %d \n",m);
    close(fd);
    wait(NULL);
    unlink("myfifo");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Did you run it in the debugger and trace the values for `c` and `m`? Good luck.

Comment: Better code would check the return value of `read(fd, &m, sizeof(int))` before using `m`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your child process never writes to the fifo. It simply opens it, generates a random number, then closes it. Try a `write`:

```
// inside fork() == 0 block
write(fd, &n, sizeof(n));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was too focused thinking my read wasn't right, did not even think about that. I have to pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 2):

It addition to what @Brian Tracy said, you should also make the parent process wait for the child process to finish writing to the file before the parent reads from it.

Comment: The `read` system call blocks, so I think the parent process will simply wait for data to be put into the pipe by the child.

Comment: But, isn't it not right to assume that the child will go before the parent?  If the file is empty then won't parent read a blank file?  I haven't touched c for a while, so I may be wrong with how `read` works.